# Do any sects other than Sri-Vaishnavas worship Viswaksena?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, vishwaksena

Being generally familiar with major Hindu sects, I never heard of Vishwaksena till recently.  SriVaishnavas like to say that when they worship an elephant-headed God, they are worshiping Vishwaksena or his assistant and not Vinayaka - but is he worshiped by any other Hindus?

Comment: Knowing him and worshiping him are different issues.

Answer (score 3):

Vishvaksena or Vishwaksena, also known as Senai Mudalvar (Sena Mudaliar) and Senadhipathi (all literally "army-chief"), is the commander-in-chief of the army of the Hindu god Vishnu and the gate-keeper and "chamberlain" of Vishnu's abode Vaikuntha.

Answer: "Yes, Vishvaksena is worshipped"

> **Vishvaksena is worshipped before any ritual or function in some Vaishnava sects. He occupies an important place in "Vaikhanasa and
>   Pancaratra temple traditions", where often temple festivals begin with
>   his worship and procession**.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvaksena

---

- His worship has been discussed in Kurma Purana ,  Kalika Purana ,  Pancharatra text Lakshmi Tantra

---

- Tirumala Tirupati Devsthanams tradition also worships Vishvaksena, as per Vaikhanasa Agama. In the temple rituals, Sri Vishwaksena is worshipped first.

ref: http://www.tirumala.org/STVishwaksenaTemple.aspx

Comment: Copy paste from Wiki is not considered a good answer here.

Comment: I have added further more information (with other references) on his worship

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - do any other Hindus besides Ramanujiyas worship him?

Comment: @SK This does answer the question. Note the "Vaikhanasas". Ramanujists are Pancharatras.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Please use the term SriVaishnavas, it makes the reference clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Forget what Śri-Vaiṣṇava worship or not, the deity of Viṣvaksena has scriptural basic in the   *paurāṇika* literature, and as such may be worshipped by anyone. That's another thing, if certain people of certain sects, nowadays might exlusively worship him or not worship him, as per sectarian beliefs.

This is what Agni Purāṇa says -

> [Chapter 24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083112.html) - Mode of constructing the sacrificial pit and the oblations unto fire
>
> नारद उवाच:
>
> गुरुः संशिक्षयेच्छिष्यान् तैः पूज्यो नामभिर्हरिः ।
> विश्वक्सेनं यजेदीशं शङ्खचक्रगदाधरम् ॥ ५६ ॥
>
> > Nārada said:
>
> > 56. The preceptor has to instruct the disciples thoroughly. Hari must be worshipped by them by (the recitation of his) names. **The Lord
> >     Viṣvaksena (whose powers go everywhere), who bears the conch, disc
> >     and mace has to be worshipped.**
>
> तज्जपन्तञ्च तर्जन्या मण्डलस्थं विसर्जयेत् ॥५७॥
>
> > 57. **(Then that deity) stationed in a circular altar, (and. who is frightening) (is worshipped) with the fore-finger and is requested to
> >     leave.**
>
> विष्णुनिर्माल्यमखिलं विष्वक्सेनाय चार्पयेत् ।
> प्रणीताभिस्तथात्मानमभिषिच्य च कुण्डगं ॥५८॥
> वह्निमात्मनि संयोज्य विष्वक्सेनं विसर्जयेत् ।
> बुभुक्षुः सर्वमाप्नोति मुमुक्षुर्लीयते हरौ ॥५९॥
>
> 58. & 59. **The entire remnants of offerings to Viṣṇu, must be offered to
>     Viṣvaksena.** Then having bowed down and sprinkled (with waters), (their
>     own persons), (the disciples) having placed the fire of the pit on
>     their own person, Viṣvaksena is permitted to leave. One who is
>     desirous of enjoyment gets all things. One who is desirous of release
>     from mundane existence. gets merged in Hari.

**This seem to suggest that in a Yajña, it is imperative to worship Viṣvaksena, after Viṣṇu, notwithstanding whatever sectarian beliefs exists.**

---

`Being generally familiar with major Hindu sects, I never heard of Vishwaksena till recently.`

References to Viṣvaksena are also found in Skanda Purāṇa (which is considered predominantly a Śaiva Literature.). Here's one of them -

> [Chapter 10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371712.html) - Glorification of the Gift of Umbrellas: The Story of Hemakānta
>
> श्रुतदेव उवाच:
>
> तेन स्मृतो महाविष्णुर्विष्वक्सेन स्वमंत्रिणम् ।
> उवाच तूर्णं त्वं गच्छ यमदूतान्निवारय ॥ ६६ ॥
>
> > Śrutadeva said:
> >
> > 66. **Recollected by him, Mahāviṣṇu said to his minister Viṣvaksena:** “You go
> >     quickly and restrain the messengers of Yama. Protect Hemakānta who was
> >     engaged in the holy rite pertaining to Vaiśākha.